# stringByAppendingString and retain dilemma

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, retain, autorelease

I will post downside 3 variant of a sample method that uses autorelease famous method stringByAppendingString.(non-arc sample project in xcode 4.6.2.IOS project)

Sample Block 1: returns nothing.just a weird points to nothing.but not null.
Sample Block 2: returns nothing too!.
Sample Block 3: returns A1A2A3. as expected but I think it has leak.

My Questions are:
a) **sample method 1 working as expected in MAC project.But not in IOS Project.**
b) is sample block 3 - includes a leak ?
c) look at comments in Sample Block 2. word_ becomes A1,A1A2 and nothing.why ?
d) what would you code your-own of same method in a different ways?.Im looking for the safe standart method.

thanks.

---

**SAMPLE BLOCK 1**

```
-(NSString*)sampleMethod
{
    NSString *word_=@"";
    NSString *a1=@"A1";
    NSString *a2=@"A2";
    NSString *a3=@"A3";

    word_=[word_ stringByAppendingString:a1];// word_ is A1
    word_=[word_ stringByAppendingString:a2];// word is nothing but another pointer
    word_=[word_ stringByAppendingString:a3];// word is nothing too but pointer changed.
    return word_;
}
```

**SAMPLE BLOCK 2**

```
-(NSString*)sampleMethod
{
    NSString *word_=@"";
    NSString *a1=@"A1";
    NSString *a2=@"A2";
    NSString *a3=@"A3";

    word_=[word_ stringByAppendingString:a1];// word_ is A1
    word_=[[word_ stringByAppendingString:a2]retain];// word is A1A2
    word_=[[word_ stringByAppendingString:a3]retain];// word is nothing !
    return word_;
}
```

**SAMPLE BLOCK 3**

```
-(NSString*)sampleMethod
{
    NSString *word_=@"";
    NSString *a1=@"A1";
    NSString *a2=@"A2";
    NSString *a3=@"A3";

    word_=[[word_ stringByAppendingString:a1]retain];// word_ is A1
    word_=[[word_ stringByAppendingString:a2]retain];// word_ is A1A2
    word_=[[word_ stringByAppendingString:a3]retain];// word_ is A1A2A3
    return word_;//returns as expected but I think leaks method in this method.
}
```

---

My Answer :Just because I was nothing did wrong.and collected variable values by debug process steps very sharp.

but somehow it is solved after clean project.hope this may save hours for someone.or dont know maybe something went wrong in memory chip addresses.

Comment: if your code doesn't do what it is supposed to do put in a breakpoint and inspect it, if you see it not doing what the code says, it is time to clean.

Comment: FYI, the idiomatic way to write this is `NSString *word_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", a1, a2, a3]`.

Comment: I think it was just an example to understand how memory management works. Otherwise he could return @"A1A2A3".

Comment: How are you examining these strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is the only method that gets the memory management correct. The second one leaks two and the third one three NSString instances. If you don't get the string "A1A2A3" from the first method the error is somewhere outside that method.

For every retain message you send you also have to send a release or autorelease message in the same method, unless your method name starts with alloc or copy. In that case the caller needs to release the returned object.

Comment: Sample Block 1 returns A1A2A3 in Mac App. but emptystring in IOS.(returns a weird pointer that doesnt give any error but treats like an emptystring)

Comment: well. Im sure It was not a nightmare. I just collected values one by one and reported here. after cleaning project.First Sample Block worked as expected.I cant ensure the reason.

Answer (score 3):

> a) which sample block 3 - includes a leak ?

Every use of `-retain` in your sample is unexpected and can introduce a leak.

> b) look at comments in Sample Block.word_ becomes A1,A1A2 and nothing.why ?

Double check that, please.

> c) what would you code your self of same method in a different ways?.Im looking for the safe standart method.

You could use a mutable string, for example:

```
- (NSString*)sampleMethod
{
    NSMutableString * word = NSMutableString.string;
    NSString *a1=@"A1";
    NSString *a2=@"A2";
    NSString *a3=@"A3";

    [word appendString:a1];
    [word appendString:a2];
    [word appendString:a3];

    return [NSString stringWithString:word];
}
```

or a format string:

```
- (NSString *)sampleMethod
{
    NSString *a1=@"A1";
    NSString *a2=@"A2";
    NSString *a3=@"A3";

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", a1, a2, a3];
}
```

then just mix and match based on your actual inputs.

Comment: NSMutableString.string is logically incorrect: the dot notation should be used only to access properties.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri that's really just your preferred coding convention -- not incorrect or illogical.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Apple's docs never say that, and actually offer contrary examples (e.g. `array.count`). Dot syntax is a general way to call accessors, whether they are part of a declared property or not. If it's an accessor, it is semantically correct to use dot notation.

Answer (score 2):

The second and third block contain a leak. The general rule is that you retain what you want to own, and you release it when you don't need it anymore. The first block is perfectly fine: you're returning an autoreleased string, which will be retained by the caller if he wants to own it, or if not, it will be released at the first autorelease pool that will be cleaned.

In the second block you're doing this:

```
word_=[[word_ stringByAppendingString:a2]retain];// word is A1A2
word_=[[word_ stringByAppendingString:a3]retain];// word is nothing !
```

The string @"A1A2" has a retain count of 2, it will have a retain count of 1 at the next autorelease pool drain, but you have lost any reference to it, so it's a leak. As for retaining the string @"A1A2A3", that's incorrect too: the caller will decide if he wants to retain it or not. The third block is incorrect for the same reasons.

Comment: I felt same: sample block 1 is what it should.
but sample block 1;returns nothing as seen in question.

Comment: What do you mean that is returns nothing?

Comment: Sample Block 1 returns A1A2A3 in Mac App. but emptystring in IOS.(returns a weird pointer that doesnt give any error but treats like an emptystring)